# Getting complicated average values for pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple DataFrame with 2 columns - date and value. I need to create another DataFrame with would contain an average value for every month of every year. For example, I have daily data in range from 2015-01-01 till 2018-12-31
I need averages for every month in 2015, 2016 etc.
Which is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by month period with [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and `mean`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('m'))['col'].mean().reset_index()
```

Another solution with year and months in separate columns:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df1 = df.groupby(['year','month'])['col'].mean().reset_index()
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2015-01-02','2016-03-02','2015-01-23','2016-01-12','2015-03-02'],
                   'col':[1,2,5,4,6]})
print (df)
         date  col
0  2015-01-02    1
1  2016-03-02    2
2  2015-01-23    5
3  2016-01-12    4
4  2015-03-02    6

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('m'))['col'].mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
      date  col
0  2015-01    3
1  2015-03    6
2  2016-01    4
3  2016-03    2

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df2 = df.groupby(['year','month'])['col'].mean().reset_index()
print (df2)
   year  month  col
0  2015      1    3
1  2015      3    6
2  2016      1    4
3  2016      3    2
```

Comment: Getting `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: It means there are not datetimes, check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, checking now. They were regular datetime values... Not the `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

Comment: @user3751086 - yes, it depends of data, sometimed pandas can convert datetimes to `Timestamp`s, sometimes not, so necessary `to_datetime`. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the monthly average values of a Data Frame when the DataFrame has daily data rows, I would:

1. Convert the column with the dates , `df['dates']`into the index of the DataFrame `df`: `df.set_index('date',inplace=True)`
2. Then I'll convert the index `dates` into a month-index: `df.index.month`
3. Finally I'll calculate the mean of the DataFrame  **GROUPED BY MONTH**: `df.groupby(df.index.month).data.mean()`

I go slowly throw each step here:

#### Generation DataFrame with dates and values

- You need first to import Pandas and Numpy, as well as the module `datetime`

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  ```
- Generate a Column `'date'` between 1/1/2019 and the 3/05/2019, at week 'W' intervals. And a column `'data'`with random values between 1-100:

  ```
  date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='3/05/2018', freq='W')
  df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
  df['data']=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
  ```
- the `df` has two columns `'date'` and `'data'`:

  ```
          date  data
  0 2018-01-07    42
  1 2018-01-14    54
  2 2018-01-21    30
  3 2018-01-28    43
  4 2018-02-04    65
  5 2018-02-11    40
  6 2018-02-18     3
  7 2018-02-25    55
  8 2018-03-04    81
  ```

#### Set `'date'`column as the index of the DataFrame:

```
    df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
```

- `df` has one column `'data'` and the index is  `'date'`:

  ```
              data
  date            
  2018-01-07    42
  2018-01-14    54
  2018-01-21    30
  2018-01-28    43
  2018-02-04    65
  2018-02-11    40
  2018-02-18     3
  2018-02-25    55
  2018-03-04    81
  ```

#### Capture the month number from the index

```
    months=df.index.month
```

#### Obtain the mean value of each month groupping by month:

```
    monthly_avg=df.groupby(months).data.mean()
```

#### The mean of the dataset by month `'monthly_avg'` is:

```
    date
    1    42.25
    2    40.75
    3    81.00
    Name: data, dtype: float64
```